# Catching then Fragment got changed in FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-pageradapter

I'm trying to catch a moment then user has switched to the next Fragemnt in FragmentStatePagerAdapter. I have tried to override onPause() function inside my Fragment, but it does not called, until user has switched two pages (probably, because of animation).

I also have tried to override the onResume() function, and have found out, that it is called for two fragments at the same time.

Is there a function what should indicate witch fragment being switched on?

I'm thinking now to override FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem and keep the list of created items, so I can at least refer to Fragment from a separate function, but is there is a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to catch a moment then user has switched to the next Fragemnt in FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

IMHO, that is not the job of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but rather of whatever activity or fragment hosts your `ViewPager`.

> Is there a function what should indicate witch fragment being switched on?

Call [`setOnPageChangedListener()` on your `ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOnPageChangeListener%28android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener%29) to register an `OnPageChangedListener`, to find out when the user changes pages.

Comment: Silli me, I forget about the listener. Thanks!